# How to include " in a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string

How do I include the " character in a string.

For example `said = "John said "Hi""`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are also a set of Control Characters available:

Try

```
Dim s as String = "John said " & ControlChars.Quote & "Hi" & ControlChars.Quote
```

I find this much more readable than multiple quotes stacked together.

Answer (score 17):

You need to double up the quotes to escape them in VB

e.g. `said = "John said ""Hi"""`

Answer (score 5):

Add Chr(34) to the string!

Something like... Console.Write("Hello " + Chr(34) + "World" + Chr(34))

Answer (score 4):

In VB.NET you must use 2 quotes: `"John Said ""Hi"""`