# How to keep character " as a part of string

Tags: vb.net

I am new to VB

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr = "00101"

Dim Rat As String
Rat = "0"
```

I wish to build new string that will contain `myStr` but with character " 
I mean that final string `FinStr` should look like this:

```
FinStr = "AT+COPS=1,2,"00102",0"   //where 0 is RAT
```

So how to keep the character " ?

What is the best function to build string?

Can I do:

```
FinStr = "AT+COPS=1,2,\"" & myStr & "\"," & Rat
```

Thanks

Comment: Google "vb escape quote"

Comment: You can also do `FinStr = "AT+COPS=1,2," & Chr(34) & "00102" & Chr(34) & ",0"`. Chr(34) will give you the quotation marks.

Comment: Duplicate of [how to include " in a string vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687579/how-to-include-in-a-string-vb-net)

Comment: I wrote this:  and got that

Comment: Sorry I wrote this line:                                                                            tmpstr = ser.SendMsg("AT+COPS=1,2," & tmp & OperatorName & tmp & "," & 0) but the result was not as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

There are also a set of Control Characters available:

Try

```
Dim myStr As String = ControlChars.Quote & "00101" & ControlChars.Quote
```

I find this much more readable than multiple quotes stacked together.

If I understand your expected result, I would think something like this is what you want:

```
Dim myStr As String
myStr =  ControlChars.Quote & "00101" &  ControlChars.Quote 

Dim Rat As String
Rat = "0"

FinStr = "AT+COPS=1,2," & myStr & "," & Rat
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to put double quotes in your string. The first option is to double the amount of quotes:

```
Dim MyString As String = """Hello, I am a string!"""
```

Notice that there are three quotes in the beginning and end of the above string. This is because the very first and the very last one represents the beginning and end of a string.

In order to put a quote in the middle of the string you only have to type two quotes "". *Example:* `"He stopped for a moment, and yelled: ""I like bananas!"" "`

---

The second option is to use the `Chr()` function:

```
Dim MyString As String = Chr(34) & "Hello, I am a string!" & Chr(34)
```

`Chr(34)` represents the quotation mark character.

---

If you want to read more about the `Chr()` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

---

And if you want to read more about putting quotation marks in your string: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k4fw5%28v=vs.90%29.aspx